# Which word means 'log in'?

Tags: translation, simplified-characters

Are there any differences between 登陆,登入,and 登录 ?

Which is the correct words to represent 'log in'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

登入 means log-in and 登出 means log-out. This pair is pretty understandable. 入 emphasizes "in", and 出 emphasizes "out".

As a computer term, people normally use "**登录**" instead of "登入" to represent logging into computer. The "录" in "登录" means "to record (记录)"。This is like a check-in process, you must record your name before you are allowed to go into the system.

登陆 however means disembark or landing. Type "登陆" for "登录" is an unfortunately widely spread misuse. This is wrong. However, decades ago when the phrase "surf the net" or "online surfing" was popular, 登陆 happened to match the figuratively representation of "leave the water (the net), go on land (a website)". So it was widely accepted. So even though it is dogmatically an incorrect usage, you don't need to correct other people anyway.

Comment: if want to represent logging, should use "登录中" instead of "登入中" as "登入" mean log in?

Comment: @JohnJoe Yes, as a computer term, you normally should say "登录" instead of "登入"。 On the other hand, it sounds awkward to say "登入中",  you'd better add a destination after 入 because 入 indicates a direction, say "正在登入系统..." In fact, "登录中...", "正在登录..." or "正在登录中, 请稍后..." are what most system used in real systems and can be considered as a convention, you should stick to them.

Comment: @JohnJoe Also please note that, "中" doesn't means "ing". "正在" means "ing" while "中" means in the middle of a process. So if you want to say, I'm logging in a computer, you should say "我正在登录" instead of "我登录中"。

Comment: thanks,very clear explanation.

Comment: @JohnJoe No problem. By the way, there is a typo of my previous comment. It should be "稍候" instead of "稍后" in the context。

Answer (score 7):

- 登陆 means landing. It may also be a typo of 登录.
- 登录 means login, used in mainland. <sup>[ref](https://www.microsoft.com/zh-cn/language/Search?&searchTerm=login&langID=124&Source=true&productid=0)</sup>
- 登入 means login, used in Taiwan and Hong Kong. <sup>[ref](https://www.microsoft.com/zh-cn/language/Search?&searchTerm=login&langID=129&Source=true&productid=undefined)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Mainland China:

- 登录  log in
- 退出  log out

Taiwan & Hong Kong

- 登入 log in
- 登出 log out

---

登陆 to land, landing

> 诺曼底登陆 Normandy landings (battle of WWII)

> 2018年9月16日，超强台风“山竹”**登陆**中国广东省江门市。
>
> On 16 September 2018, Super Typhoon Mangkhut **made landfall** in Jiangmen, Guangdong, China.